# Predicate Logic Notation: What does a "dot" mean?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, mathematical-foundations

What does a dot (.) mean in predicates?

$\forall a \in A. \exists d \in D. H(a,d)$

Especially, how is the above different to

$ \exists d \in D. \forall a \in A. H(a,d)$

I've never seen this used in German lecture scripts.

Comment: I've seen used colons too. Often the separator is omitted when followed by another quantor.

Comment: The dots here just separate the $A$ and $D$ from the stuff after them.

Comment: It's used in place of parenthesis around the quantified formula. $$\forall a \in A (\exists d \in D (H(a, d)))\;\text{vs}\;\forall a \in A. \exists d \in D . H(a, d)$$ so the $.$ (or $:$ often) quantifies over everything to the right

Comment: Just delete the dots and you will be fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The dot just means "such that"; it's often omitted.

The difference between the two formulas is the difference between "everybody has a mother" and "there is somebody who is everybody's mother."

Comment: Thank you, and a comma means "such that", too?

Comment: @nxrd A comma where? If it's after a quantified statement, then probably. But, e.g., the comma in "$H(a,d)$" is just separating the arguments of the relation.

Comment: I've seen several notations used. The $.$ is particularly popular in logic involving the lambda calculus, which also uses it as a delimiter, e.g. $\lambda x \ldotp x$.

Comment: @David Richerby I mean something like $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq z \implies n^2 \geq 4$. I can read and understand that, but somewhere in my brain I am a bit confused by commas and dots

Comment: @nxrd There's nothing to be confused by. It's just punctuation to make things easier to read. It doesn't have any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in $\forall x. P(x)$, the "such that" reading of the dot (or the space, if we don't like to write dots) doesn't make sense grammatically as it does for the existential. One could say, I suppose, "it holds that", or something like that.

Comment: Whoops, I meant this as a comment to David Richerby's answer, sorry...